# Fabric Canvas reset all objects and mouse events

Tags: angularjs, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric canvas to draw rectangle on two mouse clicks.I am using Angular.js along with fabric.When I logged in to the application the rectangle drawn position changes after two mouse clicks.

I totally unaware about how to reset and refresh fabric js canvas. For any queries see my previous questions including code.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've requested on two prior questions that you **cease asking for urgency** in your questions - this is not how to address volunteers. Are you not reading comments, or are you actively ignoring them? Please be aware that all questions have equal value here, and no-one may jump the queue.